# Google API regarding billing

Tags: google-workspace, google-developers-console

We want to get account-related info like account type, the total number of users for which license is bought, billing info like amount and renewal date, and other related information through API. Is there any API of that sort? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the inquiry I guess you are a Workspace Reseller, and you want to automate the tracking / generate reports of several billing related activities of your customers. You can do that using the [Google Workspace Reseller API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest) [1].
For example:

- You can use [REST Resource: subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/subscriptions) to get the information for your customers (including when they were created, their products and their number of licenses).
- Also there are several actions (called methods) that you can perform, including the ability to [increase the number of seats (licenses)](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/subscriptions/changeSeats), or change the [customer’ renewal settings](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/subscriptions/changeRenewalSettings).

[1] https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest